# What library to link to on Windows 7 for JNI_CreateJavaVM?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am building a first working version of a JNI application in C++.  I do not believe the specific details of the application are important for this question.  If they are, I will append them.

My code compiles without error.  However, there is a single linker error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12
```

I understand that `JNI_CreateJavaVM` is not included in `jvm.lib` / `jvm.dll`.  However, I cannot determine what library I *do* need to link to for this function.

I have JDK installed (but only 64-bit - and this is a 32-bit C++ application, which may be relevant).

Can somebody please assist?

Comment: `I have JDK installed (but only 64-bit - and this is a 32-bit C++ application, which may be relevant).` I think thats your answer. Try downloading the 32-bit JDK.

Comment: That was it.  Quite obvious even as I wrote it.  I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined reference to \`JNI\_CreateJavaVM' windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930567/undefined-reference-to-jni-createjavavm-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Steps to link the jvm.lib to your project in Visual Studio:

- Right click on the project -> properties.
- On the Properties dialog    box, add jvm.lib under
  Linker->Input->AdditionalDependencies area.
- Lastly write jvm.lib path(like "C:\Program
  Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\lib") under
  Linker->General->AdditionalLibraryDirectories

After those steps, your project can link to jvm and work well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a Java application from C++ I suggest using exec and creating a new process esp if one is 32-bit and the other 64-bit.

Comment: Actually, it is easy enough for me to install & run a 32-bit JDK/JRE.  Were I forced to do without 32-bit JRE, I would probably use sockets, as my C++ and Java components need to communicate.

Comment: Sockets are a good way to communicate and if there is a problem with the process for some reason, you can kill it safely.